# Nginx FastCGI Perl configuration

Tags: perl, ubuntu, nginx, fastcgi

I am trying to get FastCGI to work with Perl CGI in FastCGI mode.  By that I mean that I can run Perl CGI scripts on Nginix without any issues but it does not appear (based on performance measurements) that my scripts are running in FastCGI mode.  I've seen mentions about spawn-fcgi but nothing recent or details on how to implement with current versions of Nginx and Ubuntu.

I am relatively new to Linux.

Environment info:
Ubuntu 22.04 hosted in the "cloud"
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Tutorial I followed: https://techexpert.tips/nginx/perl-cgi-nginx/
I have installed fcgiwrap.
CGI works, HTTPS works.
I am enclosing the bulk of my Perl CGI script within

```
use CGI::Fast;

while(my $q = new CGI::Fast)

{

# all my code

}
```

My script is doing a simple write and query from a very small SQLite3 database (4 columns, 500 rows, 290k db size).

I am testing across the Internet.
Script execution performance is about half of a second (.42 seconds per page) or 345ms.  That is about the same as IIS Windows CGI.

I also saw that requesting a simple HTML file only has marginally better performance.

I understand that there is a lot more to performance testing than the preceding.  The point is that I think there is something missing with my FastCGI configuration.  I imagine it has something to do with me needing to launch the Perl FastCGI script somehow and then somehow connect that to Nginx.   If anyone can point me in the right direction or provide example config files, that would be great.  Thanks all!

Comment: After making a request but after the request is complete, do you still see the CGI script process running?

Comment: @ikegami when using htop and running a load generation script from a remote client (Python) I can see the Perl script popping in and out, so I guess that means that CGI script process is not running in a persistent mode.